# HTML CSS Table Width Not Working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table where the first column is 10% of the page width.  The remaining 90% is then divided into two further equal width columns. (I am doing this as I also want to include a span row across two columns.)

The **width: 50%** does not work, instead the two columns are pushed up close.  I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome.

I have included a simplified snippet below.

```css
.news-table {
  display: table;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.news-tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.news-td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-table" style="width: 100%;table-layout:fixed">
  <div class="news-td" style="width: 10%">
    Narrow
  </div>
  <div class="news-td" style="width: 90%">
    <div class="news-tr">
      <div class="news-td" style="width: 50%">
        Wide1
      </div>
      <div class="news-td" style="width: 50%">
        Wide2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the table family of tags; there are quite a few, and if nothing else works use the colspan attribute of the  **td**  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Table normally use proper tag  not div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Tables</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table  class="news-table">
         <tr class="news-tr">
           <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
           <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="news-tr">
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the divs so that I can also create a responsive page that does not use a table for mobile devices.

Comment: there are table responsive too like bootstrap... if you use div then probably you are referring to grid

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add 
    `float: left`
 and `float: right` to the columns, and if that doesn't work I would also try adding `position: relative` to it.

Here is a code pen I made for another answer that may be helpful: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqvyYp?editors=1000

Edit: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZpPrR?editors=1000 this one might suit your needs better